# О слове "прикол"

Tags: этимология

Современный жаргон "прикол". О нем пишут, что он появился в языке из речи наркоманов. Действительно ли это так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ерунду пишут. 
Уколоть, подколоть существовали в языке задолго до наркоманов.
Отсюда и прикол.